# Build project by CMake, has a problem for use of "undeclared identifier 'nullptr' "

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

My project use CMake build android-ndk,when I `run app` to phone,that will appear `use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'`

The code is build, for log :

> **/Users/userName/Desktop/GuideMachine/SDK-Android/app/src/main/cpp/ivw-jni/ivw-jni.cpp:25:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
>   IvwRes(size_t nSize) : buffer(nullptr), size(nSize) {**

Comment: You should add `add_definitions(-std=c++11)` to CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure C++ 11 support, on the version of compiler you have older one is default, and there nullptr is actually undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need c++11, it's possible to just add define to compiler: in CMakeLists.txt add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Dnullptr=0")
```